# Can I add a Groovy Eclipse script to Windows start menu?

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I have successfully written a Groovy script in Eclipse with the Groovy plug-in.  It goes through all the mp3 files in a folder and sets the tags.

At the moment I open Eclipse and the run the script from within Eclipse.  Is there a way I can add the script to the Windows start menu to avoid having to open Eclipse?  Can I create an exe file from the script?

I'm sure this information is out there, I think the problem is that I don't know the correct search terms to find it, so even some pointers to the correct terminology for this process would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You basically want a way to run groovy scripts from outside of Eclipse plugin. Then you can add it to your start menu or anywhere else you want.

There are shell scripts called 'groovy' or 'groovy.bat' depending on your platform which is part of the Groovy runtime.

Once the runtime is installed you can just run groovy like any other script

```
groovy foo/MyScript.groovy [arguments]
```

Take a look at [Groovy - Running](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running) and [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Groovy/article.html#commandline) tutorial section.